# Importing SVGs as React components from external source fails - "Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type... "

Tags: reactjs, svg, create-react-app

In a create-react-app based components, importing SVGs as React components works well as long as the SVG files are inside the project:

```
 import {ReactComponent as Switch} from "../../../assets/svgs/switch.svg";
```

But after moving all the images to an AWS S3 bucket, I receive the following error:

Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/svg+xml". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I understand there is a clash between the expectation to a .js file (a component) and the .svg file received from outside.

How is it possible to still import SVGs as components from external sources?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was given the following answer:

SVG files that are imported as components must be stored inside the project and not externally at the server, because they must be part of the source code, as their transformation occurs at build/compile time and not at runtime.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).